# Why is the port being added when I call window.location.href

Tags: javascript

For some odd reason, when I call `window.location.href`, port 80 is being added to the URL before the redirect takes place. The resulting URL looks like so:

`https://domain:80/user/create?createProvider=1`

Why is it adding port 80, when the redirect is happening for a secure page to begin with?

The code is simply:

```
  window.location.href= "/user/create/?createProvider=1";
```

Comment: Are you hitting the original page on port 80? Did you add a `<base>` tag? Can you give us a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your problem?

Comment: The original page is being served over SSL.. port 443

Answer (score 0):

It seems your server is configured in a way as to treat port 80 as ssl.

The Port is a part of your `host`. Much like .com, .net, .online...

And JS reads what the browser is giving it. And the browser accepts what the server (nginx?, apache?) is serving it.

When you call:

```
window.location.href= "/user/create/?createProvider=1";
```

you are essentially concatenating `window.location.host` with your string

Comment: I'm hosted in google app engine. What's really strange it doesn't behave that way everywhere. On some pages it works as expected, but not others. It's quite maddening.

Answer (score 0):

Just in case any poor soul encounters this issue, I wanted to share what I found to "fix" it.

As stated in the question, my reactJS app, hosted on google app engine, would append :80 to the domain upon calling window.location.href. And would only do so in certain cases: If there was a slash as the last character of the URL, or if there's a slash followed by a question mark anywhere in the URL. Avoiding those 2 things alleviated the issue.